# Which punctuation would be used here?

Tags: semicolons, colons, em-dashes

I am wondering what punctuation would be used if you are telling the reader to look at a certain thing, and then telling them what they will see. Would it be "...transcript: You..." or "...transcript-You..." ? Or would it be just a period?

"Please look at the charging document in the file, and compare it with the trial transcript. You will notice that my trial was missing a member of the jury."

Comment: All three ways, and a fourth, using a semicolon, are fine. It's up to you. I would use a colon, since its force is to tell the reader to look ahead to what follows it.

Comment: Whichever style you use, don't capitalise the word after *transcript* unless it starts a new sentence (or unless it is a proper noun).

Comment: Wouldn't the "you" be capitalized since it could be the start of a new sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules on when to use commas, colons, semicolons and dashes?](What are the rules on when to use commas, colons, semicolons and dashes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @AlanCarmack, and I, too, would use a colon.

As per Strunk and White, *The Elements of Style* (Macmillan, 1979, pp. 7-8):

> "*Use a colon after an independent clause to introduce* a list of particulars, an appositive, *an amplification*, or an illustrative quotation." [emphasis added]

In the case of your example, the second sentence is an amplification of the first. Hence:

> "Please look at the charging document in the file, and compare it with
>   the trial transcript: you will notice that my trial was missing a
>   member of the jury."

The colon focuses the more of the attention of the reader on what follows the colon.

Comment: The @ ping thing doesn't actually ping people when you use  it in an answer. But I appreciate the shout out. In other words, I didn't get pinged, I just happened to read your answer...

Comment: @AlanCarmack Alan. Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: Wouldn't the "you" be capitalized since it could be the start of a new sentence?

Comment: @Richard I didn't either, till someone told me.

Comment: @LedZepp No, one wouldn't capitalize *you*. BTW, your original two full sentences were fine. "Please ..." has the effect of leading the reader to the sentence that follows. You could also consider a dash, which according to Strunk and White is less formal than the colon.